# NetBeans remote editing for Java projects?

Tags: netbeans, ide

My project makes use of the Play! framework, so I don't need an editor that can compile. I generally like NetBeans, but would like to remote edit source files on the server to save time. I also often switch between my desktop/netbook for development, so remote editing would save me from syncing a dev environment.

All my searches for remote editing for Netbeans suggest that it's available for PHP projects, but I don't see anything for Java projects. If Netbeans doesn't support remote editing for Java projects, is there an IDE that does?

Edit: I develop on Windows but the server runs Linux.

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention your operating system, but there are solutions for Windows where you can make a FTP server appear as a regular drive in Windows. That way you can use any editor/IDE you like regardless whether that supports FTP access or not.

A quick search diggs up this:
http://www.ghacks.net/2006/08/03/how-to-mount-an-ftp-drive-in-windows/

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked. Yes obviously OP can setup SMB or alternative network drive, that's completely irrelevant to the question asked