# How to setup a Netbeans php remote server project and keeps files on the remote server? (I don't want the files to be downloaded)

Tags: php, ftp, remote-server, netbeans-8

The remote files are large in size and I want to keep them on the server and not have them downloaded to my computer. I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.

Comment: You want to edit the files on a live application? That's not recommended at all. Or is the remote server for development/testing? It is possible, though it is better to download the data (or a representative subset of it) and use it locally. What OS are you on? You should be able to get a file system driver that connects to a remote server via (S)FTP - though it will be pretty slow.

Comment: I am running on Windows 7.  I want to edit the live files and not have them downloaded first, in spite of all the benefits. Wanted to do it with Netbeans. CodeLobster does it, Notepad++ does it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NetBeans remote editing for Java projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663713/netbeans-remote-editing-for-java-projects), and [see this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=netbeans+remote+file+edit).

Comment: The only one tool I know is PHPDesigner that allows you to edit files directly at ftp

Comment: Thanks guys. I ended up not using Netbeans.